Audio Classification using CNN predicting wrong all the time
I am trying to do an audio classification model that can take an audio as input and predict the genre of the music. The issue is that the accuracy is high, it is performing well on the test set but when I give it any audio (even from the dataset) in the last part of the code, the model predicts it wrong, I can't find the issue, please if someone can help with it!
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import librosa
#%%
DATA_PATH = "./genres_original"
#%%

def extract_features(file_path, mfcc=True, chroma=True, mel=True):
    signal, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr=None)

    features = []
    if mfcc:
        n_fft = min(2048, len(signal))  # Adjusted to handle short signals
        mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=signal, sr=sr, n_mfcc=40, n_fft=n_fft).T, axis=0)
        features.extend(mfccs)
    if chroma:
        chroma = np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(y=signal, sr=sr).T, axis=0)
        features.extend(chroma)
    if mel:
        mel = np.mean(librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=signal, sr=sr).T, axis=0)
        features.extend(mel)

    return np.array(features)

# Define the preprocessing function
def preprocess_data(X):
    X_preprocessed = []
    for file_path in X:
        features = extract_features(file_path)
        X_preprocessed.append(features)
    return np.array(X_preprocessed)
#%%

def prepare_datasets(test_size, validation_size):
    X, y = [], []

    genre_mapping = {
        0: 'blues',
        1: 'classical',
        2: 'country',
        3: 'disco',
        4: 'hiphop',
        5: 'jazz',
        6: 'metal',
        7: 'pop',
        8: 'reggae',
        9: 'rock'
    }

    for i, (dirpath, _, filenames) in enumerate(os.walk(DATA_PATH)):
        if dirpath is not DATA_PATH:
            label = dirpath.split("/")[-1]
            for file in filenames:
                file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                X.append(file_path)
                y.append(i - 1)

    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size)
    x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=validation_size)

    x_train = preprocess_data(x_train)
    x_validation = preprocess_data(x_validation)
    x_test = preprocess_data(x_test)

    x_train = x_train[..., np.newaxis]
    x_validation = x_validation[..., np.newaxis]
    x_test = x_test[..., np.newaxis]

    return x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test, genre_mapping


#%%
def build_model(input_shape):
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=input_shape),
        keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
        keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same'),
        keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        keras.layers.Flatten(),
        keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])
    return model
#%%
def predict(model, X, y):
    X = X[np.newaxis, ...]
    prediction = model.predict(X)
    predicted_index = np.argmax(prediction, axis=1)
    print("Target: {}, Predicted label: {}".format(y, predicted_index[0]))
    predicted_genre = genre_map[predicted_index[0]]
    print("Predicted genre:", predicted_genre)

#%%
import random

def apply_data_augmentation(x_train, y_train):
    augmented_x_train = []
    augmented_y_train = []
    for i in range(len(x_train)):
        augmented_x_train.append(x_train[i])
        augmented_y_train.append(y_train[i])

        #Time stretching
        factor = random.uniform(0.8, 1.0)  # Adjust factor range to avoid stretching too much
        stretched_signal = librosa.effects.time_stretch(x_train[i].squeeze(), rate=factor)
        # print("Stretched signal shape:", stretched_signal.shape)

        if len(stretched_signal) < x_train.shape[1]:
            stretched_signal = np.pad(stretched_signal, (0, x_train.shape[1] - len(stretched_signal)), mode='constant')
        else:
            stretched_signal = stretched_signal[:x_train.shape[1]]

        # print("Padded/truncated stretched signal shape:", stretched_signal.shape)
        augmented_x_train.append(stretched_signal[..., np.newaxis])
        augmented_y_train.append(y_train[i])

        #Pitch shifting
        steps = random.randint(-4, 4)
        shifted_signal = librosa.effects.pitch_shift(x_train[i].squeeze(), sr=22050, n_steps=steps)
        # print("Shifted signal shape:", shifted_signal.shape)
        shifted_signal = np.pad(shifted_signal, (0, x_train.shape[1] - len(shifted_signal)), mode='constant')
        # print("Padded shifted signal shape:", shifted_signal.shape)
        augmented_x_train.append(shifted_signal[..., np.newaxis])
        augmented_y_train.append(y_train[i])

        #background noise
        noise = np.random.randn(len(x_train[i]))
        noise_signal = x_train[i].squeeze() + 0.005 * noise
        # print("Noise signal shape:", noise_signal.shape)
        noise_signal = np.pad(noise_signal, (0, x_train.shape[1] - len(noise_signal)), mode='constant')
        # print("Padded noise signal shape:", noise_signal.shape)
        augmented_x_train.append(noise_signal[..., np.newaxis])
        augmented_y_train.append(y_train[i])

    return np.array(augmented_x_train), np.array(augmented_y_train)
#%%
x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test, genre_mapping = prepare_datasets(0.15, 0.15)
#%%
# Apply data augmentation
x_train_augmented, y_train_augmented = apply_data_augmentation(x_train, y_train)
x_train_combined = np.concatenate((x_train, x_train_augmented), axis=0)
y_train_combined = np.concatenate((y_train, y_train_augmented), axis=0)
#%%
from keras.optimizers import Adam

input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], 1)
model = build_model(input_shape)
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#%%
history = model.fit(x_train_combined, y_train_combined, validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation), batch_size=32, epochs=12)
#%%

Output:
Epoch 1/12

339/339 [==============================] - 23s 64ms/step - loss: 1.9216 - accuracy: 0.3482 - val_loss: 1.5777 - val_accuracy: 0.4517

Epoch 2/12

339/339 [==============================] - 22s 64ms/step - loss: 1.4682 - accuracy: 0.4943 - val_loss: 1.0933 - val_accuracy: 0.6449

Epoch 3/12

339/339 [==============================] - 21s 63ms/step - loss: 1.2388 - accuracy: 0.5695 - val_loss: 0.9394 - val_accuracy: 0.7258

Epoch 4/12

339/339 [==============================] - 21s 63ms/step - loss: 1.0568 - accuracy: 0.6360 - val_loss: 0.8218 - val_accuracy: 0.7493

Epoch 5/12

339/339 [==============================] - 21s 63ms/step - loss: 0.8998 - accuracy: 0.6910 - val_loss: 0.7568 - val_accuracy: 0.7833

Epoch 6/12

339/339 [==============================] - 21s 62ms/step - loss: 0.7754 - accuracy: 0.7312 - val_loss: 0.7581 - val_accuracy: 0.7676

Epoch 7/12

339/339 [==============================] - 21s 63ms/step - loss: 0.6842 - accuracy: 0.7675 - val_loss: 0.6881 - val_accuracy: 0.7911

Epoch 8/12

339/339 [==============================] - 22s 63ms/step - loss: 0.5885 - accuracy: 0.8008 - val_loss: 0.6340 - val_accuracy: 0.8146

Epoch 9/12

339/339 [==============================] - 22s 65ms/step - loss: 0.5291 - accuracy: 0.8244 - val_loss: 0.6105 - val_accuracy: 0.7990

Epoch 10/12

339/339 [==============================] - 22s 64ms/step - loss: 0.4623 - accuracy: 0.8461 - val_loss: 0.5868 - val_accuracy: 0.8251

Epoch 11/12

339/339 [==============================] - 22s 64ms/step - loss: 0.3930 - accuracy: 0.8687 - val_loss: 0.6235 - val_accuracy: 0.8512

Epoch 12/12

339/339 [==============================] - 21s 63ms/step - loss: 0.3450 - accuracy: 0.8849 - val_loss: 0.6200 - val_accuracy: 0.8355

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print('\nModel performance on test set:')
print('Test loss:', test_loss)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)

15/15 - 0s - loss: 0.4993 - accuracy: 0.8400 - 223ms/epoch - 15ms/step

Model performance on test set:
Test loss: 0.49930423498153687

Test accuracy: 0.8399999737739563

x_to_predict = x_test[41]
y_to_predict = y_test[41]
predict(model, x_to_predict, y_to_predict)

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 53ms/step

Target: 4, Predicted label: 4

Predicted genre: hiphop

def extract_and_preprocess_features(file_path):
    # Extract features
    features = extract_features(file_path)
    # Preprocess the features
    features_preprocessed = np.array([features])
    features_preprocessed = features_preprocessed[..., np.newaxis]  # Add a dimension for the model
    return features_preprocessed

def predict_genre_from_audio_file(audio_file_path, model, genre_mapping):
    features = extract_and_preprocess_features(audio_file_path)

    # features = features[np.newaxis, ..., np.newaxis]

    prediction = model.predict(features)

    predicted_index = np.argmax(prediction, axis=1)

    predicted_genre = genre_mapping[predicted_index[0]]

    return predicted_genre


audio_file_path = "./genres_original/blues/blues.000002.wav"
predicted_genre = predict_genre_from_audio_file(audio_file_path, model, genre_mapping)
print("Predicted genre:", predicted_genre)

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step

Predicted genre: disco


What is your extract_and_preprocess_features() function?

I just added the extract_and_preprocess_features() function in the question!

Your preprocessing code does not make any sense. First you compute MFCCs etc. Then you take the mean across time. All temporal information has now been removed. Then in apply_augmentation you attempt to time-stretch etc these features as if they are are audio. And then you process this with a CNN which expectes 2 dimensional data like time, features.
